# arch linux- error:failed to get canonical path of 'airootfs' (grub to USB installation)

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, grub2

I'm trying to install arch-linux for the first time. everything was OK till I tried to install "grub" boot-loader to a USB drive.

I am working by the WIKI ARCH LINUX guide.

both of this commands worked with no errors:

```
# mkdir -p /mnt/usb ; mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/usb

# grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck --debug --boot-directory=/mnt/usb/boot /dev/sdc
```

but the next command return an error:

> failed to get canonical path of 'airootfs' :

```
# grub-mkconfig -o /mnt/usb/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

can any one assist?

(tried to `arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash`  on this one the command is not found).

Comment: Could you link to the guide you are following? Is it this [one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_a_USB_key)?

Comment: no. i was using this:https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#LVM_on_LUKS                                      and: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners'_guide#Installation

Comment: I'm running into the same issue - did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Another "mee too" problem. What is so broken with Arch that it can't boot after an update. This is the third time in about 18 months.

Answer (score 22):

Try adding `--root-directory=/mnt` to the `grub-install` command. It seems to be undocumented, but I saw it mentioned on some forum, and it worked for me.

Comment: This is a good workaround and I voted it up, however, the better solution is [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/579519/478908) below. It's better, in my opinion, because it explains the cause of the problem and also gives a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Hit this same problem a short while ago, and figured it out. It seems like you may not have the `grub` package installed in your target file system.

So `arch-chroot` to the target (`/mnt/usb`), run `pacman -S grub`, and then execute `grub-install` and `grub-mkconfig` with correspondingly updated parameters to account for the `chroot`.

Answer (score 4):

I may be three years too late, but for googlers like myself who happened upon this thread, here is the answer:

The problem is that you are running the `grub-install` and `grub-mkconfig` programs from the archiso live media. If you `arch-chroot` into the mounted filesystem, the error will be corrected.

By appending `--root-directory=mnt` to the `grub-install` options, you can bypass the issue, but `grub-mkconfig` does not include such a nifty workaround.

Comment: BANG!   awesome  `--root-directory=mnt`

Answer (score 1):

try executing `arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash` first